# Instantiating a new TextToSpeech give a NullPointer Exception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm a noob in Android dev.

I'm using TextToSpeech and it works well on several platforms, except on one particular phone (Running android 4.4.2).

There the instantiation of TTS gives a null-pointer exception:

```
private TextToSpeech mTTS;
// ...
mTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, mTTSInitListener);
```

The Sdk version used is the minimum specified: 19 (and to my nuderstanding, TTS was added in API level 4 (thus Android 1.6)

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        applicationId "myapp"
        versionCode 73
        versionName "1.1.0"
```

Question is: what can make TTS unavailable / non-instantiable ?

thx

Comment: share error logcat....

Answer (score 0):

First you should check that the device is capable of TTS or not.
Like below code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");
                            try {
                                startActivityForResult(intent, Constant.SEARCH_VOICE);
                                overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
                                Toast t = Toast.makeText(mContext, getResources().getString(R.string.speech_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                t.show();
                            }
```

Comment: Thx a lot Koustuv. Meanwhile I figured out that there was indeed no TTS installed on this device (I somehow imagined that it was embed in android).

Comment: However, I had already tried this type of suggestion, but I then run in trouble with the "startActivityForResult" which is not recognized / or with a different signature in the compat lib... still struggling but getting closer ;-)

Comment: **"startActivityForResult" which is not recognized** I assume you are not inside activity/fragment..!

Comment: You're right, I was in a service. moved some code in the main activity and it is much better ! (yeah, total noob mistake ;-) Also installed a TTS on the device and no more NPE... (seems so obvious now) thx A LOT for your help, I am back on tracks now !

Comment: Is this check also valid for text-to-speech as this seems to check for speech-to-text support?